# Forget Password is not working after upgrading to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4.3, forgot-password

I clicked forgot password and then input data.
I received message reset password, so I send change password but got error like this.
How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355894/magento-2-4-4-password-reset-link-always-expired

Comment: thanks, but my error is in front end. and I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your email templates in your custom theme are outdated. Remove the overridden templates in Magento_Customer/email or search for differences with the original templates in vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email.